# Spring ResponseEntity best practice

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am new to RESTful web services in general, and am learning the Spring implementation of web services.

I am particularly interested in learning how to properly use ResponseEntity return types for most of my use cases.

I have one endpoint:

```
/myapp/user/{id}
```

This endpoint supports a `GET` request, and will return a JSON formatted string of the User object whose ID is `{id}`. I plan to annotate the controller method as producing JSON.

In the case that a user with ID `{id}` exists, I set a status of 200, and set the JSON string of the user in the body.

In the event that no user exists with that ID, I was going to return some flavor of a 400 error, but I am not sure what to set in the body of the ResponseEntity. Since I annotate the endpoint method as producing JSON, should I come up with a generic POJO that represents an error, and return that as JSON?

Comment: yes, you should return generic pojo and in case of no user id exist you should return the error or invalid status within the pojo.

Comment: If nothing exists, there is nothing to return. Simply respond with an empty HttpResponse that has the status code `404` for "Resource not found"

Answer (score 6):

You don´t need to use a generic Pojo, using RequestMapping you can create different responses for every Http code. In this example I show how to control errors and give a response accordingly.

This is the RestController with the service specification

```
@RestController
public class User {

    @RequestMapping(value="/myapp/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getId(@PathVariable int id){

        if(id>10)
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found");

        return ResponseEntity.ok("" + id);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({UserNotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> notFound(UserNotFoundException ex){

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(
            new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage(), 404, "The user was not found") , HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Within the getId method there is a little logic, if the customerId < 10 It should response the Customer Id as part of the body message but an Exception should be thrown when the customer is bigger than 10 in this case the service should response with an ErrorResponse.

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String message;
    private int code;
    private String moreInfo;

    public ErrorResponse(String message, int code, String moreInfo) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
        this.moreInfo = moreInfo;
    }

    public String getMessage() {

        return message;
    }

    public int getCode() {

        return code;
    }

    public String getMoreInfo() {

        return moreInfo;
    }
}
```

And finally I'm using an specific Exception for a "Not Found" error

```
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the event that no user exists with that ID, I was going to return
>   some flavor of a 400 error, but I am not sure what to set in the body
>   of the ResponseEntity. Since I annotate the endpoint method as
>   producing JSON, should I come up with a generic POJO that represents
>   an error, and return that as JSON?

This is definitely a possible solution, if you want to add e.g. a more specific reason why the request failed or if you want to add a specific I18N message or just want to generify your API to provide some abstract structure.

I myself prefer the solution @Herr Derb suggested, if there is nothing to return, don't return anything. The returned data may be completely unnecessary/unused and the receiver may just discard it if the return code is anything else than 2XX.

This may be related:
http://www.bbenson.co/post/spring-validations-with-examples/
The author describes how to validate incoming models and builds a generic error response. Maybe this is something you want to do...